# how to submit bulk record of following array using eloquent or query builder

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have sale product form where user will receive cash against product at cash counter, and products could be many. How to submit that record at once using eloquent and query builder with following array pattern

```
Array
   (

    [_token] => jsVji1V6cTt5XmD2XgWyA7GEH5lvPlYbYWtUPIrt

    [productId] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[quantity] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
    )

[amountReceived] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100
        [1] => 500
    )

[deliveryLocation] => Array
    (
        [0] => london
        [1] => new york
    )

   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an associative array like below and insert:

```
for($i=0;$i<count(data['productId']);$i++){
 $temp[]=array('productId'=>$data['productId'][$i], 'Quantity'=>$data['Quantity'][$i],'amountReceived'=>$data['amountReceived'][$i]);
}

Model::insert($temp);
```

[Docs are here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)